# Celerybeat send task only when I use app.control.purge()?

Tags: docker-compose, celery, django-celery, celery-task, celerybeat

I am using celery and celery beat and rabbitmq in docker. However, my celery beat works only if I firstly empty the queue using **app.control.purge()**. Moreover, celerybeat send task only one times! and if I want to run tasks I should purge all tasks that are in the queue(s) again.
Here is my task template:

```
@shared_task
def test_task():
    print('Hello')
```

and here is my celery configurations:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
from celery import Celery
import os

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'configuration.settings')
app = Celery('configuration')
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')
app.autodiscover_tasks()

@app.on_after_configure.connect
def setup_periodic_tasks(sender, **kwargs):    
    from applications import test_task
    from celery.schedules import crontab
    sender.add_periodic_task(crontab(minute='*/1'), test_task(), name='test')
```

Is there any idea what should I do?
Thanks

Comment: Use `timedelta(minutes=1)` instead of `crontab(minute=f'*/1')`, which may not even be the correct way to use crontab()...

Comment: Actually I use '*/1' and it was a typo in my post. So, I still have problem.

Comment: So you did not try the suggested timedelta() instead?

Comment: I check it too, but still not work.